# Parse second XML element in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML file in the following format:

```
<item id="xxxxxx">
    <Category>xxxxx</Category>
    <EmpEmail>xxxxxx</EmpEmail>
    <EmployeeName>xxxxxxx</EmployeeName>
    <InteractionType>xxxxxx</InteractionType>
    <pxCreateOpName>xxxxxx</pxCreateOpName>
    <pyID>xxxxx</pyID>
    <WorkerInfo>
        <Country>xxxxx</Country>
        <JobTitle>xxxxxx</JobTitle>
        <Region>xxxxx</Region>
    </WorkerInfo>
    <InsKey>xxxxx</InsKey>
</item>
```

I am able to parse tags in the item element using

```
for item in root.findall('item'):
    row = []
    if item.find('Category') is not None:
        category = item.find('Category').text
    else:
        category = ''
    row.append(category)
```

But I cannot retrieve the tags under WorkerInfo using `for item in root.findall('WorkerInfo')`.  What would be best way to get to this element?

Comment: try looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add another loop like below. Also my indenting might be off.

```
for item in root.findall('item'):
row = []
if item.find('Category') is not None:
    category = item.find('Category').text
else:
     for itemsecond in root.findall('WorkerInfo'):
         if item.find('WorkerInfo') is not None:
             category2= item.find('Category').text
             if category2 is not None:
                row.append(category2)
row.append(category)
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like WorkerInfo contains nested elements, and your first line `for item in foot.findall('item'):` will only loop over top level elements. So, at some point `item` will be set to WorkerInfo, but that is not the same as being set to its sub-elements. You will need a nested loop to loop over those. Try this:

```
for item in root.findall('item'):
    for workerItem in item.findall('WorkerInfo'):
        // Do whatever you want with the elements of WorkerInfo here
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to `WorkerInfo` and retrieve its tags, you can use a similar structure. Just call `findall()` passing in `'WorkerInfo'` and loop through its children.

```
for item in root.findall('item'):
    for worker in root.findall('WorkerInfo'):
        row = []
        for child in worker:
            row.append(child.tag)
```

With your example, `row` becomes `['Country', 'JobTitle', 'Region']`